# Determining shutdown time of ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have an `ExecutorService` that processes some tasks. The client threads **can** call `shutdown()` on the `ExecutorService`. I want to run some cleanup code after the `ExecutorService` has completely shutdown. Is there a mechanism to run a callback method after the `ExecutorService` has completed its shutdown.

NOTE:

1. I **cannot** call `shutdownNow()`
2. The clean-up code must run **after** the `shutdown()` is completed.
3. The `ExecutorService` is a `newCachedThreadPoolExecutor()`;

Answer (score 2):

Start another thread/executor-managed-runnable that checks [`ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) in a try-catch statement in a loop until it returns `true`, then run your shutdown handling code. The loop is necessary because the method might return prematurely when interrupted.

Something like this:

```
public class ShutdownHandler implements Runnable {

    private final ExecutorService service;

    public ShutdownHandler(final ExecutorService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean terminated = false;
        while (!terminated) {
            try {
                terminated = service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                // check again until terminated
            }
        }

        // your shutdown handling code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This would allow running the clean up code *asynchronously* from the thread submitting work into the executor. For a *synchronous* way, check @Andrei's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would extends and override:

```
public class MyExecutorService extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        super.shutdown();
        // do what you need to do here
    }
}
```

Something like that

Comment: Wouldn't this run the code on the first call to `shutdown()`, instead of after the whole `ExecutorService` has completed its shutdown?

Comment: Why would you need to extend and override, why not just call it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you call executorService.invokeAll(myListOfCallableTasks) and them executorService.shutDown()  the thread calling that will block until all the tasks are finished:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: That's a very elegant way to do it when you can block the calling thread. Didn't think of that one :)

Comment: @PhilippReichart Just an observation that this approach would not work when using the ScheduledExecutorService.